# Index optimization across multiple instances

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzindex

There is a database that is replicated from INST-1, where it is created, to multiple other instances.

```
Instance INST-1
Database SALES
Schema dbo
Table ATABLE

INST-1.SALES.dbo.ATABLE
```

The SALES database is replicated to multiple other instances. The other instances are like "marts" from which other groups gather information.

```
INST-2.SALES.dbo.ATABLE
INST-3.SALES.dbo.ATABLE
INST-4.SALES.dbo.ATABLE
```

The replication tool copies the entire SALES database, including indexes, to the other instances. Each instance will have differing utilization that would suggest different indexes.

Since the replication tool does not support a different set of indexes on each instance, producing an optimal set of indexes on INST-1 may degrade performance on the other instances. Is there a good way to use sp_BlitzIndex to analyze across all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_BlitzIndex doesn't have any multi-server analysis tools built in, nor do we plan to add them.

We've talked about building a new script do to that kind of analysis, and if you'd like to contribute code or watch its progress, [subscribe to this Github issue](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/3183).